# Speeding up loop in console app which is using EF and ASP.NET Identity's AddPasswordAsync method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, console-application, asp.net-identity

I have a C# console app in which I'm using ASP.NET Identity's AddPasswordAsync to hash passwords in my MSSQL database.  I have about 50,000 records to update.  I'm running it on my test db and it's taking forever.

Is there a way to speed this up?

```
foreach (var user in db.Member.Where(u => u.is_deleted == false).Select(u => new { id = u.id, pass = u.web_password, hash = u.password_hash }).ToList())
            {
                if (user.hash == null)
                {
                    if (user.pass == null)
                    {
                        string newPass = RandomString(8);

                        var result = userManager.AddPasswordAsync(user.id, newPass).Result;
                        Console.WriteLine(
                            "UserID: {0}, Password: {1}, Hashed: {2}",
                            user.id,
                            newPass,
                           result.Succeeded);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var result = userManager.AddPasswordAsync(user.id, user.pass).Result;
                        Console.WriteLine(
                            "UserID: {0}, Password: {1}, Hashed: {2}",
                            user.id,
                            user.pass,
                           result.Succeeded);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Maybe a [Parallel.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720(v=vs.110).aspx) loop can help you instead of using a normal foreach loop.

Comment: Thanks for this tip, @Horizon. I haven't been able to get back to this but I had no idea about the Parallel.ForEach.  I'll be sure to try it out.

Answer (score -1):

May be something like (assuming that AddPasswordAsync populates Hash column):

```
    int i = 500;    
    while ( i > 0) {
        i = 0;
        foreach (var user in db.Member.Where(u => u.is_deleted == false && u.hash == null).Select(u => new { id = u.id, pass = u.web_password, hash = u.password_hash }).Take(500).ToList())
        {
           i++;
                if (user.pass == null)
                {
                    string newPass = RandomString(8);

                    var result = userManager.AddPasswordAsync(user.id, newPass).Result;
                    Console.WriteLine(
                        "UserID: {0}, Password: {1}, Hashed: {2}",
                        user.id,
                        newPass,
                       result.Succeeded);
                }
                else
                {
                    var result = userManager.AddPasswordAsync(user.id, user.pass).Result;
                    Console.WriteLine(
                        "UserID: {0}, Password: {1}, Hashed: {2}",
                        user.id,
                        user.pass,
                       result.Succeeded);
                }
            }
    }
```